# Trying to compile using JAR file in intellij-idea getting ERRORS java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror

I am using the JAR file [Java-WebSocket-1.5.2.jar](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/releases/tag/v1.5.2) and I followed their [example](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/wiki#server-example), I am using Intellij Idea-ce and I am getting the errors:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/bin/java -javaagent:/opt/intellij-idea-ce/lib/idea_rt.jar=35201:/opt/intellij-idea-ce/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/root/my/Project/out/production/Project:/tmp/Java-WebSocket-1.5.2.jar SimpleServer
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.java_websocket.AbstractWebSocket.<init>(AbstractWebSocket.java:50)
    at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer.<init>(WebSocketServer.java:208)
    at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer.<init>(WebSocketServer.java:181)
    at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer.<init>(WebSocketServer.java:149)
    at SimpleServer.<init>(SimpleServer.java:10)
    at SimpleServer.main(SimpleServer.java:49)
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at        java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 6 more
```

Since the code is exactly from their example it makes me believe it has something to do with my project setup. I tried researching these errors and everyone says to just add the JAR to the modules under the Project management, which the JAR files are there. And from the first quot of errors the JAR files is indeed in the -classpath compile command so I am unsure why I would be getting this.

If anyone has any idea why this could be happening it would be greatly appreciated. I am completely lost and do not want to have to deal with Maven if I have the JAR file.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: There are no references to slf4jin the example you provided. Share the whole project sources including .idea directory

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov thank you for poitining that out. seems so obvious now. I added the slf4jin jar to my project and it works now. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

as @KonstantinAnnikov pointed out, I needed to have a reference to org/slf4j/LoggerFactory in my classpath so adding the slf4j JAR file to the project solved the issue.